# Changing column name in EF forces migration (even with Column attribute)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, quartz.net

I've created some classes in C# using database-first approach and I am currently refactoring these classes to make the names more human readable.

However, changing the name of the property and applying the original in the `ColumnAttribute` still forces a migration.

This seems to apply when I rename composite keys that are referenced by other entities/tables.

For example, changing this:

```
    [Key]
    [Column("SCHED_NAME", Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(120)]
    public string SCHED_NAME { get; set; }
```

to:

```
    [Key]
    [Column("SCHED_NAME", Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(120)]
    public string SchedulerName { get; set; }
```

creates a migration like this one:

```
        DropForeignKey("dbo.QRTZ_TRIGGERS", new[] { "SCHED_NAME", "JOB_NAME", "JOB_GROUP" }, "dbo.QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS");
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.QRTZ_TRIGGERS",
            c => new
                {
                    SCHED_NAME = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 120),
                    TRIGGER_NAME = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 150),
                    TRIGGER_GROUP = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 150),
                    JOB_NAME = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 150),
                    JOB_GROUP = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 150),
                    DESCRIPTION = c.String(maxLength: 250),
                    NEXT_FIRE_TIME = c.Long(),
                    PREV_FIRE_TIME = c.Long(),
                    PRIORITY = c.Int(),
                    TRIGGER_STATE = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 16),
                    TRIGGER_TYPE = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 8),
                    START_TIME = c.Long(nullable: false),
                    END_TIME = c.Long(),
                    CALENDAR_NAME = c.String(maxLength: 200),
                    MISFIRE_INSTR = c.Int(),
                    JOB_DATA = c.Binary(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.SCHED_NAME, t.TRIGGER_NAME, t.TRIGGER_GROUP })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS", t => new { t.SCHED_NAME, t.JOB_NAME, t.JOB_GROUP });

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS",
            c => new
                {
                    SCHED_NAME = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 120),
                    JOB_NAME = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 150),
                    JOB_GROUP = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 150),
                    DESCRIPTION = c.String(maxLength: 250),
                    JOB_CLASS_NAME = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 250),
                    IS_DURABLE = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    IS_NONCONCURRENT = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    IS_UPDATE_DATA = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    REQUESTS_RECOVERY = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    JOB_DATA = c.Binary(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.SCHED_NAME, t.JOB_NAME, t.JOB_GROUP });

        DropTable("dbo.QRTZ_TRIGGERS");
        DropTable("dbo.QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS");
    }
```

The `CreateTable` statement is identical to the initial one.

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

If you want human readable names to appear on your application, you will need to change the names inside Column() attribute. What you're trying to do above is changing the actual names of the column. Check below how I changed a name to desired name inside Column() attribute but kept original name as it is -

```
[Key]
[Column("SchedulerName", Order = 0)]
[StringLength(120)]
public string SCHED_NAME { get; set; }
```

Comment: Perhaps I described the scenario poorly. The column name in the database needs to remain the same, it's the property name in the class I wish to change. The column attribute does just that, lets you specify the column name whilst having another in the class. What you are suggesting maps the property to a column in the database named 'SchedulerName' - which does not exist.

Comment: Oops! What I meant is using DisplayName attribute instead of Column.

Comment: Display(Name = "SchedulerName") instead of Column("SchedulerName").

Comment: That attribute is related to UI elements - those that honor it - and has nothing to do with the class property name. I wish to change it without forcing a migration.